# What's an appropriate icon to represent the concept of 'all'

Tags: icon

In my app, I have a collection of objects that I'm allowing the user to filter. To represent each filter, currently starred objects, watched objects and the user's object, I use the icons pictured below:

[image: The icons in my app, a star, eye and person]

However, I'm having trouble coming up with a way to represent the concept of *all* objects being visible. Does anyone know of a good icon to represent this?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the content of your app.

Comment: In the past I've used an 'x' on top of a funnel (filter)

Comment: The content of my app is GitHub repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in this particular context, you can replace the concept of 'all' with 'clear selected filters' so perhaps something that means 'clear' or 'reset' or the like would work.

One suggested example is that in the past I've used an 'x' over a funnel (which I was using to identify filtered lists) in apps.